# Как копировать/создать/вставить компонент vue?

Tags: vue.js, vue3

У меня есть компонент содержащий несколько input'ов (см изображение)

Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки добавить (плюсик), он дублировался ниже.

Как это реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал Vue.createApp(ИМЯ_КОМПОНЕНТА).mount('#mount-point') но консоль ругается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создаем массив в data()

```
inputs: []
```

При нажатии кнопки:

```
this.inputs.push({
    placeholder: this.inputsPlaceholder // Любое значение, у меня переменная
  })
```

В основном компоненте:

```
<div v-for="input in inputs" :key="input.id">
    <inputs:placeholder="input.placeholder"/>
</div>
```

Компонент inputs:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <div class="input-title">input*</div>
  <input type="text" name="" required :placeholder="placeholder">
</div>
```